# How can one find the name with which a Node.js CLI script was called?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I have a script that should behave differently depending on what it is called as (think `vimdiff`). `__filename` is specifically designed to give the real name of the file, following aliases and symlinks and such. Is there a way to get the original command name?

So that if I call:

```
node_script --foo=bar
```

Or:

```
scriptForNode --foo=bar
```

And they both reference the same code, how can I get the `node_script` or `scriptForNode` part out?

(Ideally, it should deal with aliases, bash functions, and symlinks equally well, but I'll take what I can get.)

Answer (score 1):

How about [`process.argv`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.7/api/all.html#process.argv)`[0]`?

(Or perhaps that should be `process.argv[1]`, since [0] would probably return `node`).

Comment: I wish. Doesn't work, at least not in node v0.3.7 (latest). It holds the realpath of the file, resolving all aliases, symlinks, and so forth. No good.